# Error 1683 "Index tag is not found" in Foxpro

Tags: foxpro

How can I solve "Index tag not found" foxpro error. I'm using vbf 9.0 and I've been doing what other sites told such as that deleting and re indexing my database but nothing comes up so far. Help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are seeing this error in an application that you have which uses the DBF table. What is happening is that there is code in the application that says something like:

```
set order to tag tagwhatever
```

or

```
use mytable order tag whatever
```

... but the index called 'whatever' is not defined, i.e. is not present in the structural index .CDX file.

You could add it but unless you know what to index on this is a bad idea. Does the application have any sort of reindexing/database rebuild functionality within itself?

Comment: yes it has rebuild index function but whenever i delete the index and run the rebuild index function nothing happens

Comment: Do you have an old backup of the data that you could open in VFP and examine the indexes to determine which one is missing?

Comment: unfortunately i don't have it in me even the source code. that is why i'm having a hard time dealing with it. it was just a turnover program that supposedly i'm just for support. anw Thank you alan for replying

Comment: what do you think has the error? the cdx file or the database itself?

Answer (score 0):

With vbf 9.0 probably you meant VFP 9.0. There is a tag for VPF.

Remove the reference to the tag you get error on.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check where you have named the main key of the table matches the one that appears in the "DATA"